# Pro Tools, Windows/PC & Strange File Name Shortening

Tags: pro-tools, windows, pc, file-organization

How many people here are doing sound effects work on a PC Pro Tools? I've been getting this odd problem where sound effects that are re-saved (like if I did a save copy) have their names shortened, but it's almost as though random letters get dropped, instead of just shortening the end of the name. I'm assuming this has something to do with PC and limitations on file name length?

Any advice? It's annoying mostly from a workflow standpoint, though I'm still also trying to figure out what might be the best option for sfx library management at this point. This, in turn, will dictate how I end up naming or renaming files, I'm sure.

Possibly of note, but when this renaming occurs, it seems that the file ID remains the same, so when a Mac isn't able to find the files by name, it can by file ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hey James,

What version of PT are you using?  When you save copy, are you saving it as 5.1 - 6.9 or earlier?  That will shorten character names exceeding 31 characters.

And the letters that get dropped aren't random, they are vowels only, so no worries.

James